# Conditional Formatting Formula with Cell Reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This formula gives me an error and I can't figure out what's seems to be wrong

`=AND(H3>TODAY()+$J$*30,H3<=TODAY()+$L$1*30)`

But if I hardcode the days like this then it works:

`==AND(H3>TODAY()+30,H3<=TODAY()+90)`

I'm trying to highlight range of cells from today + # of month to today + # of month.

For example, Today+30, Today+90 should highlight Aug, Sept and Oct. (Assuming today is July something)

Comment: Could you please provide some screenshots of the sample data and what the expected results should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error lays here, `$J$`. Change that to a cell `$J$1`

```
=AND(H3>TODAY()+$J$1*30,H3<=TODAY()+$L$1*30)
```

If your goal is to see if H3 is today plus n months, you should look into `EDATE`. Maybe you can change around your formula to not work with these 30 and 90 numbers. Unless that's necessary

Comment: I took your suggestion and change the formula to `=AND(H3>EDATE(TODAY(),$J$1-1),H3<=EDATE(TODAY(),$L$1-1))` works much better :) Thanks